# List items in navigation bar/unordered list stay left justified after using margin: 0 auto

Tags: css, centering

After applying "margin: 0 auto" to an unordered list, a horizontal nav bar, I am able to center the list element but the items contained within the list are left justified within the list. The examples I've seen online don't say anything about having to re-position the li elements so I suspect I'm doing something wrong. I can see that the list is actually centered because of the black border I have placed around it but the items are not.

```
#navBarList 
{
    width: 25%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    list-style-type: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-width: 3px;
    border-color: black;
    border-style: solid;     
}

#navBarList li 
{
   float: left;   
}
---------------------------------

<div id="navBarDiv">
    <ul id="navBarList">
        <li>Plots</li>
        <li>Reports</li>
        <li>Map</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Wait, what do you want to do? Center the text?  Why are you floating the li elements?

Comment: Please post some of the related HTML.

Comment: It's a horizontal navigation bar. The HTML code is just 3 li elements. I'm floating the li elements to get the horizontal effect. Writing this just gave me an idea. Perhaps that's my problem.

Comment: Maybe it's the floating?

Comment: Default alignment is left. To create a horizontal menu bar you have to center the elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to guess you meant to give a width to the `li` elements and not it's containing `ul` element.  Get rid of the `margin: 0 auto;` unless you want to center within the `ul`'s container.  `list-style-type: none;` should also be on the li elements, but I don't think that matters<strike>, as floating them displays them as (floating) blocks and not list items</strike>.  The corrected CSS is as follows:

```
#navBarList 
{
    overflow: hidden;
    border-width: 3px;
    border-color: black;
    border-style: solid;     
}

#navBarList li 
{
    list-style-type: none;  
    width: 25%;
    float:left;
}​
```

[JSFiddle of your example (modified)](http://jsfiddle.net/Fn3gQ/)

You may also need to add `text-align: center;` to the `#navBarList li` rule if you intended to center the text within the `li` elements.

Edit: Actually, I might have been wrong about the list items. Floating them in chrome makes them not act like list items, and I was thinking about another rule (inline items are floated as block elements).  Not sure about that one.